# XML documentation comments in a separate file

Tags: c#, xml, comments, xml-documentation

I find a lot of topics that describe the way through

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

But when I give such a description to several functions of the class, it starts to distract and disturb me. Can I put it in a separate file or hide it? To see only in `IntelliSense`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide those comments by clicking the small `[-]` icon at the left hand side.

[image]

If you want to hide them all at once, this neat [Visual Studio Extension called NoComment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment) can help you.

Comment: I know that `[-]`. But they are constantly revealed. And the color of the closed version is distracting.

Comment: If you use the extension, it won't expand unless you explicitly do so. Also, try getting used to comments, being distracted is a habit, you can overcome it. Comments are super useful.